# ¿Cómo navegar desde un Jframe hacía otro con una ventana específica con JTabbedPane en Java?

Tags: java, netbeans

En contexto lo que quiero es hacer lo siguiente, tengo un JFrame donde guardo una serie de datos de autores de libros en una tabla, lo que quiero hacer es que al seleccionar la tabla me direccione hacía otro JFrame que contiene un JtabbedPane (pestañas) lo cual me cargaran los datos seleccionados en la columna de la tabla.

En las imágenes podrán observar que es lo que quiero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar en la imagen de arriba, contengo dentro de una pestaña una tabla donde tengo unos datos, ahora quiero que tras seleccionar un elemento, es decir una fila me direccione hacía otro Jframe que también tenga pestañas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posterior a este imagen se puede observar otro JFrame con pestañas, lo que deseo es que cuando haya seleccionado una fila de la tabla de la primera imagen, este me direccione específicamente a la pestaña del otro JFrame, es decir, como me fui de autores, vaya al otro JFrame para agregar o modificar datos de los autores, lo mismo ocurriría con el Admin, que si me voy a la tabla del Admin y seleccione una fila de su tabla, este me lleve hacía otro Jframe y me habrá directamente el panel de el.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí esta la sección de código que tengo, es decir que cuando me seleccione una fila de la tabla me lleve hacía otro Jframe donde están los paneles para insertar información, modificarla etc.

Dato: La línea de código señalada es la cuál me indica donde va estar el panel que necesito abrir.

Pero no se me ocurre algo para hacerlo, si me pudieran ayudar les agradecería mucho.

Comment: Hola amigo, debo decirte que el uso de múltiples JFrames en una misma aplicación es, en definitiva, una mala práctica. Deberías optar por opciones mejores como las ventanas modales, checa este 
enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice.

Comment: Vale comprendo, agradezco mucho el consejo que me estás dando, sin embargo si me pudieras ayudar con lo que estoy pidiendo, me ayudarías demasiado.

Comment: Creo que lo único que te haría falta es hacer visible a tu Frame no?, agregar la linea: `autor.setVisible(true);`.

Comment: Pero si digamos, deseo que me cargue directamente la otra pestaña que en este caso sería "Admin" cómo haría allí?

Comment: Pues sólo hace falta utilizar el método `JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(//indice de la pestaña)`, así como lo tienes, solo tienes que mandarle el índice correcto de la pestaña que quieres 'activar'.

Comment: Parce me funcionó, estoy muy agradecido de verdad. (y)